# how to link ipaddress to a name to allow connections when on the same router

Tags: django, ip-address, dhcp, domain-name, localserver

So I making a small website with django, and I want my colleagues to be able to connect. We all will be using the same router, and although I can ask them to connect via the address I provide http://192.168.100.xxx on port 8000. I decided to make it easier by mapping the address to a name, so they can connect via http://my_server:8000. Although I am unsure on how to come about this. Whether to do it from the router settings, or my system settings.

I've tried searching online on on how to do such, and most articles are come accross are very confusing. I would like someone to give a straightforwards approach to this.

Comment: I've done this for a couple of Servers at work on our Domain Controller. The term you want is `reverse dns lookup zone`.. you just create another entry, put in the static IP, give it the name you want and boom- all PCs connected on the Domain now have it.
If you know any specifics about the network I might be able to point you in a more specific direction.

Comment: Thank you very much, but how do I edit the hostname, and must the site be running for it to work?

Comment: It only seems to be returning the hostname of the ipaddress. Which is the ipaddress itself

Comment: I see that you've figured it out. I was wrong, it was inside `forward dns lookup zone`, and I made a another Host file for that IP and gave it a different name. That allows be to do `https://db` instead of `https://db.internal_domain_name.com` - but i guess you could have always just used the domain name. Anyways, just wanted to clarify.

Comment: honestly, still confused. I just want my friends to be able to connect to my server 192.168.xxx.xxx:8000 thru a host name like 'www.my_server.com'
Ill try nonetheless

Comment: Lol, yeah it it pretty confusing. **I** did it on my work's Windows Server, it's does the all DNS and local Active Directory, but basically you are looking for some sort of **DNS** setting.
But that's only for **internal** use. If you want it available **outside** of your network you'd have to buy a domain or use DuckDNS and open+redirect ports on your router. 
Sorry I assumed *colleagues* meant this was just an internal type thing.

Comment: Heres a guide on how to set up DuckDNS, it's a good/free starting point, https://techsparx.com/blog/2019/12/duckdns.html - you'll just have to google redirecting your ports by your router's manufacturer.
If you don't buy a static IP for your ISP, and why would you?, this is a good route cause it handels it; and I personally use it at home for my HomeAssistant instance.
Then down the road you could look into actually **buying** a domain and figuing out the whole static/non-static IP problem

Comment: ohh yes @Nealium, I thought I specified I just want it on my network. I know I have to buy it if I want it on the internet. I just want the dns for my local network. Sorry for the late reply

Comment: and I tut, it was possible to do it from the router, but I'll try the website

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a couple of your friends to connect, you can a edit the `hosts.txt` file on each of their computers to add a line like this

```
192.168.100.xxx        my_server
```

note, however, editing the `hosts.txt` file is kinda dangerous and not a scalable solution

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually aware of that, but I've been able to finally do it, turns out my firewall was the issue, but thank you nonetheless

Comment: ok good to know that @luko

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to resolve the issue, after noticing that my browser still took a while to try to connect before failing. I decided to check my firewall, turns out I just needed to enable the firewalls for python and python.exe